# The view 'ProductTemplate.Simple' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations

Tags: nopcommerce

actually i want to insert product and its count in new table when click on product using plugin. I have done this without plugin.
i copied product action method in my plugin but problem is that first call nop.web.catalog controller 's product action method then called my plugin 's product action method when wrote
@Html.Action("Product", "ProductMostviewed", new { productId = Model.Id }) in ProductTemplate.simple.cshtml

but problem is occur on @Html.Action("Product", "ProductMostviewed", new { productId = Model.Id }) in ProductTemplate.simple.cshtm .error is  " The view 'ProductTemplate.Simple' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. "

please help.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen two different things cause this error.

1. This can happen if you haven't set view to be an "Embedded Resource".
2. This can happen if you did not reference the view properly in the Controller action.  It should be something like:

   ```
   //This is right
   return View("Nop.Plugin.<namespace>.<pluginname>.Views.<ControllerName>.<ViewName>", model);

   //This is wrong
   return View(model);
   ```